# Why could the Klingons see normally using Geordi's VISOR?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-generations

In the movie ST: Generations, there is the famous scene where the Enterprise-D is blown up because the Klingon sisters were able to see through Geordi's visor the shield frequency.  You'll notice in the picture below, though, that Geordi's VISOR couldn't see with normal human vision.  Was there an upgrade to his visor after the TNG series?

[image: How Geordi could see]

[image: What the Klingons saw]

Comment: If Geordi can read those numerals, then where's the problem? Maybe, the display screen is adaptive if you are thinking about bottom photo.

Comment: I think the bigger question is whether Geordi can see people farting...?

Comment: "Was there an upgrade to his visor after the TNG series?" An upgrade? It would have been a downgrade, surely, since Geordi's visor is stated to be superior to human vision in some other episode...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [first image](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Mind%27s_Eye_%28episode%29) (from Mind's Eye) is seen from Geordi's perspective (e.g. observing a whole range of frequencies).

The second image is shown "as translated" by the Klingon's computer and is only observing the visible range of the spectrum.

Comment: That makes sense!  I thought that something like that may have been done